# App not installed issue after signing & updating the apk

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-update-app

I'm trying to update the existing App in Playstore.

Signed the APK & generated it with the existing jks file, but getting "App not installed" issue while trying to update on the old App.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you zip-aligning and obfuscating the APP code using proguard?

Comment: @Asendo,  No , we are not using Proguard

Comment: Does your device meet the minimum SDK requirements for your release APK?

Comment: @basha in your mobile current app is signed by debug key then remove that apk and install new signed apk

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers When I install the old application from playstore, then when I give an update to this application with newly signed apk then it giving an error with app not installed. but when I uninstalled the old one and installed newly created signed apk. its installing succeessfully

Comment: @Asendo Yes, I am maintaining a min sdk to 21

Comment: Did the debug APK install and run on the device? if yes create a new signing key and sign a new release APK

Comment: I am able to debug by connecting USB Cable. But the issue is with while updating to new version. I think this is not the good idea. we may lost the users

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this are mainly related to signature inconsistency of an app.
I'll recommend you use the [app signing feature on Google Play Store](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en).

This allows you to publish an update without having key conflicts. It automatically verifies and strips the signature from the new APK, and then resigns the APK with the app signing key you uploaded at the initial state to maintain consistency.